# React/Node: Where should I store the questions/answers for a trivia-like app that doesn't use an external API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

If I want to make a trivia-like React/Node app that will have around 10000 words (answers), of which maybe 5 will be displayed to the user at the same time at any given time, where should I store those 10000 words?

These 10000 words won't come from any external API, I need to make them myself and they will always be the same 10000, no need to scale.

What is the right/best way of going about it?

I need the user's progress to be saved permanently somewhere (they will have a login).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a JSON file with all your words, and read it if you dont want to use your BackEnd as an API with DataBase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been learning the whole MERN and PERN stacks, so I wouldn't mind having a backend. I will need it for the login anyways. But what would be more efficient, the JSON file or the database?

Comment: If we talk about efficient, go for database, JSON stores data in a format to be passed to and from the server to the client, but Javascript/jquery can use JSON as data objects, so database = clean, JSON = work but dirty

Comment: if it's answered your question, close this post and accept the answer